# Parse Error in JSON Format

Tags: json

Please explain what is my Parser Error in this JSON object.

```
db.products.insert({
    name: "Microsoft Surface",
    category: 'Electronics',
    model: '7G5-33333',
})
```

P.S: JSONLint says, but I can't figure out...

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
db.products.insert({
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: I think your keys should be strings too (i.e. put "name" not name etc)

Comment: @shim thank you for the suggestion, I've tried it but the error is still the same.

Comment: The example you posted is *code*, not JSON. Why are you passing the whole code to JSONLint? It seems you are not even working with JSON here, so why are you using JSONLint? I'm not going to use a C linter if I'm writing JavaScript. In other words: You are using the wrong tool for whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: JSON also requires double quotes not single quotes.

Comment: Yea, actually don't think the keys need to be in quotes. What is this, MongoDB?

What is the error you're getting (not JSONLint)?

Comment: @shim in mogno shell I have this error: '[thread1] SyntaxError: missing } after property list @(shell):14:0'

Comment: @FelixKling thank you for you answer Felix, I will take that in consideration

Comment: Try removing the comma at the end (after the model value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma at the end (after the model value).

```
db.products.insert({
    name: "Microsoft Surface",
    category: 'Electronics',
    model: '7G5-33333'
})
```

Having the comma there indicates there are more key-value pairs, so that's why you're seeing the "missing } after property list" error.

Comment: Thank you shim, I will be more careful with my commas.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
    db.products.insert({
        "name": "Microsoft Surface",
        "category": "Electronics",
        "model": "7G5-33333"
    })
```